# How to clone XMLHttpRequest object?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, clone

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', '/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Test', 'test');

let clone = ....?
xhr.send();

clone.setRequestHeader('Test2', '....');
clone.send();
```

Attempt 1

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', '/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Test', 'test');

let clone = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(xhr)), xhr);
xhr.send();

clone.setRequestHeader('Test2', '....');
clone.send();
```

**Uncaught TypeError: 'setRequestHeader' called on an object that does not implement interface XMLHttpRequest.**

Attempt 2

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', '/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Test', 'test');

let clone = new XMLHttpRequest;
Object.assign(clone, xhr);
xhr.send();

clone.setRequestHeader('Test2', '....');
clone.send();
```

**Uncaught DOMException: XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader: XMLHttpRequest state must be OPENED.**

Comment: Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What is the purpose to cloning the XMLHttpRequest object itself? What is the goal you try to achieve and is cloning really the only option?

Comment: I'm making a userscript for Tampermonkey, I need to get all the xhr parameters before send, change them and send a request with my own after sending a new request.


`
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendCopy = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (params) {
    let clone = ...;
};
`

Comment: Well, in that case you can monkeypatch `XMLHttpRequest`, intercept calls to its methods and forward them to a clone as well as the real instance. Then on also intercept `.send()` and do whatever you want with the clone you already have ready to go and configured the same as the original. You can probably wrap up everything in a Proxy to just do that for you for every method call.